# how to start my rails app in passenger using port 80

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

Hi I have deployed my rails app using passenger. but the problem is, it starts with the port 3000. I want to run my app on port 80. That is when I enter my app URL in address bar for example www.xyz.com, it should directly re-direct to my app's index page. but it does not. It goes to Apache’s welcome page. how to overcome this problem. I have tried in SO. but I did not get any solution. Thanks in advance

**This is my VH conf file**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName http://0.0.0.0:80
      # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
      DocumentRoot /var/www/School_Managements/public   
      <Directory /var/www/School_Managements/public>
         # This relaxes Apache security settings.
         AllowOverride all
         # MultiViews must be turned off.
         Options -MultiViews
         # Uncomment this if you're on Apache >= 2.4:
         #Require all granted
      </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Errr... How are you starting the application?  If you're running 'rails s' that's your problem right there.  Using Passenger you will typically configure Nginx or Apache to run the application via Passenger directly.

Comment: I have given my command like "passenger start -a x.x.x.x -p 80 -d"

Comment: I have configured everything in /etc/apache2/myapp.conf (VH)

Comment: @AnitaShalu Please show your config file

Comment: Have you added load passenger module in your apache config file? And you need to run apache on port 80 not Passenger. Apache and nginx are webservers and Passenger is an application serve, to run any webapplication we need combination of webserver and application Server. Apache will listen your request on port 80 and forward it to application server.

Comment: For rails apache and passenger configuration read this blog https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-apache-with-passenger

Comment: I have configured my load passenger. then i dont understand what did you say about running apache on port 80?

Comment: You just need to add load modules line which you got after installing apahce-passenger-module into your configuration file and just restart apache. service apache2 restart

Comment: `sudo passenger-install-apache2-module`
this will give you something like this:
`LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-2.2.2
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8`

Paste this in top of your apache conf file.

Comment: yeah i have given everything. but when I start to enter my server name in URL, it should directly redirect to welcome page. not to apache's welcome page